# Update field via url

Tags: entities, uri

Is it possible to modify a field on a node via a url string? For example, my node (1) has a field (field_stage) which I'd like to update using the following url:

www.mysite.com/node/1?field_stage=complete

I can't seem to find a lead on this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There's the [Prepopulate module](http://drupal.org/project/prepopulate)

> The Prepopulate module allows fields in most forms to be pre-populated from the $_REQUEST variable.
>
> For example, the following URL,
>
> *http://www.example.com/node/add/blog?edit[title]=this is the title*
>
> will automatically fill the Title field on a new blog post with the words "this is the title". Any field can be prepopulated this way, including taxonomy and CCK fields. You can prepopulate more than one field at a time as well.

It's only in dev for Drupal 7 but I've used it in a couple of projects and I haven't had any major problems. If it doesn't quite match your use case you could always take a look at the code, it shouldn't be that tricky to adapt for other purposes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. While this is a very handy module, I'm looking to modify an existing node, rather than pre-populating fields on a new node edit form. If it helps, my specific need is for a way to change the "status" field (custom field) of a node without having the user access the node edit page.